# BUILDS are missing from azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

**Where are the builds? How do I create a build?**

When I go to pipelines, I do not see builds:

[image]

I am a member of the `build administrators` group.

From VS, I can go to `view builds in browser`:

[image]

That correctly takes me to:

`https://myorg.visualstudio.com/myproject/_build`

Yet, it's still missing builds:

[image]

I can even query for a specific build:

`https://myorg.visualstudio.com/myproject/_build?definitionId=75&view=runs`

And here's what I get:

[image]

**Where are the builds? How do I create a build?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Builds are now called Pipelines.

To create a Pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=tfs-2018-2

Comment: annoying that the docs weren't updated, I thought someone turned down my permissions!

Comment: Yes, very annoying. Seems like bad naming: "Pipelines" containing "Pipelines" and more stuff. And apart of the bad name, they have removed the Builds Navigation panel on the left of the "Builds" window. My company works with hundreds of projects, now is difficult to find one... the filter helps a little but all the grouping folders seems gone

Answer (score 1):

The previous "Builds" interface can be accessed at the bottom of the "Where is your Code" section.
click on "Use the classic Editor"

[image: the classic builds]

CLicking that will now lead you to the "classic" interface.. for those who are following guides from 2018-2019

[image]